# Run database evolution from within scala console

Tags: scala, playframework

I have started my application from within the scala console by doing:

```
scala> import play.core.StaticApplication
scala> new StaticApplication(new java.io.File("."))
```

I got warnings that the default database needed evolutions.  How can I run these evolutions from within the scala console?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run this in console, assuming `"default"`:

```
play.api.db.evolutions.OfflineEvolutions.applyScript(new java.io.File("."), this.getClass.getClassLoader, "default")
```

Alternatively, when starting Play!, you can have it apply evolutions automatically with:

```
play -DapplyEvolutions.default=true
```

...or add the above parameter to your config.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure which version of Play @mushroom was using at the time (Play 2.2, most likely), but things have changed a bit since then. I was able to achieve the same result as @opyate by doing the following in console:

```
import play.api._
import play.api.db._
import play.api.db.evolutions._

// Start the application (instead of using `new play.core.StaticApplication(...)`)
val env = Environment(new java.io.File("."), this.getClass.getClassLoader, Mode.Dev)
val context = ApplicationLoader.createContext(env)
val loader = ApplicationLoader(context)
implicit val app = loader.load(context)

// Apply the evolutions
OfflineEvolutions.applyScript(
    new java.io.File("."),
    this.getClass.getClassLoader,
    app.injector.instanceOf[DBApi],
    "default",
    true
)
```

Here's the [2.4.x source](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.4.x/framework/src/play-jdbc-evolutions/src/main/scala/play/api/db/evolutions/Evolutions.scala#L237), and the [2.5.x source](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.x/framework/src/play-jdbc-evolutions/src/main/scala/play/api/db/evolutions/Evolutions.scala#L239). Notice that for 2.5.x, `OfflineEvolutions.applyScript` requires additional `dbName` and (optionally) `schema` parameters.

As a side note, the reason for not being able to use `new play.core.StaticApplication(...)` is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31224187/play-2-4-console-not-working-as-documented).

Comment: I also had to call `app.stop()` in a `finally` clause or the process would not terminate cleanly (i.e. Ctrl+D in the console would hang).

Answer (score 2):

I think the fastest way is:

```
play -DapplyEvolutions.default=true run
```

But you can add

```
applyEvolutions.default=true
```

to your application.conf too