# play 2.4 console not working as documented

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework

i have recently updated to play 2.4.1 (damiya) release and have always been able to enter the scala console both through intellij and by entering `activator console` in my terminal window. I would then start a new static application by entering this line of code:

`new play.core.StaticApplication(new java.io.File("."))`

as documented on the [play website itself](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.1/PlayConsole)  as well as on some answers to similar older questions on SO.

however, i am unable to get this to work on play 2.4.1, with the error being returned as :

```
<console>:8: error: type StaticApplication is not a member of package play.core
          new play.core.StaticApplication(new java.io.File("."))
                        ^ `
```

any advice on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated, the console was immensely useful to me in the past and rather essential for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Richard explains in this [commit](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/commit/688f651064fff2f2189d9e9c0734e04b6d4c304d):

> #### Refactored server start code into prod, dev, test modes
>
> This change makes the lifecycle for starting up applications much
>   clearer.
>
> - No longer need separate ServerStart implementations for Netty and   Akka HTTP because ServerProvider configuration is always loaded from
>     configuration files. Instead, separate out code according to the mode 
>     that the server runs in, because behavior can vary between modes. Now 
>     we have a ProdServerStart, DevServerStart and a DocServerStart.
> - For each mode, move the ApplicationProvider code into same file as   the new server startup code. Move code for starting up the application
>     out of the ApplicationProvider constructors and into the server
>     start code. ApplicationProviders still implement the 'get' method
>     for getting the current Application.
> - Remove TestApplication and StaticApplication, because they do the   same thing. Instead provide helpers for 'static' Applications that
>     don't need reloading.

You can do the same thing as follows:

```
play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(Array())
```

Comment: I am using play-yeoman from here https://github.com/tuplejump/play-yeoman which adds support of angular framework, but the routes related yeoman are not found.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, bjfletcher's answer only pointed me on the right path-- running `ProdServerStart` didn't actually get me a running environment (in fact, quite the opposite--

```
scala> play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(Array.empty)
Oops, cannot start the server.
Configuration error: Configuration error[application: application.conf: java.io.IOException: resource not found on classpath: application.conf, application.json: java.io.IOException: resource not found on classpath: application.json, application.properties: java.io
.IOException: resource not found on classpath: application.properties]
        at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:178)
        at play.api.Configuration$.load(Configuration.scala:103)
        at play.api.Configuration$.load(Configuration.scala:133)
        at play.api.ApplicationLoader$.createContext(ApplicationLoader.scala:91)
        at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:50)
        at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:27)
        at $line21.$read$$iw$$iw$.<init>(<console>:8)
        at $line21.$read$$iw$$iw$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line21.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
        at $line21.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
        at $line21.$eval.$print(<console>)
        ...
```

...probably due to my own inexperience with the JVM.).

Fortunately, the 2.5.x version of [Launch the Interactive Console](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/PlayConsole#Launch-the-interactive-console) provides runnable code!

The more verbose version of what we had before is now:

```
import play.api._
val env = Environment(new java.io.File("."), this.getClass.getClassLoader, Mode.Dev)
val context = ApplicationLoader.createContext(env)
val loader = ApplicationLoader(context)
val app = loader.load(context)
Play.start(app)
import Play.current
```

which can probably be saved into a `:script` or something.